# Row.render error on using Row from react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using `react-bootstrap` for its layout features. I am using the `Row` tag and getting the following error :

> Invariant Violation: Row.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be
>   returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other
>   invalid object.

My usage is as follows . Please point me out to anything I might have missed :

```
var Row = require('react-bootstrap/lib').Row;


module.exports = React.createClass({

validateForm: function() {
        console.log("i am validating the transaction details");
        var input=this.refs.form;
        return(input.validateForm());

    },
render : function(){
return(
<div>
<Row>
</Row>
  </div>
); 

}

});
```

EDIT :

Even the following gives the same error :

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');


module.exports = React.createClass({

validateForm: function() {
        console.log("i am validating the transaction details");
        var input=this.refs.form;
        return(input.validateForm());

    },
render : function(){
return(
<div>
<ReactBootstrap.Row>Hello World
</ReactBootstrap.Row>
  </div>
); 

}

});
```

EDIT :
on doing console.log(Reactbootstrap.Row) , I get the following output :

```
function (props, context, updater) {
          // This constructor gets overridden by mocks. The argument is used
          // by mocks to assert on what gets mounted.

          if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
            process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? warning(this instanceof Constructor, 'Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or ' + 'JSX instead. ) : void 0;
          }

          // Wire up auto-binding
          if (this.__reactAutoBindPairs.length) {
            bindAutoBindMethods(this);
          }

          this.props = props;
          this.context = context;
          this.refs = emptyObject;
          this.updater = updater || ReactNoopUpdateQueue;

          this.state = null;

          // ReactClasses doesn't have constructors. Instead, they use the
          // getInitialState and componentWillMount methods for initialization.

          var initialState = this.getInitialState ? this.getInitialState() : null;
          if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
            // We allow auto-mocks to proceed as if they're returning null.
            if (initialState === undefined && this.getInitialState._isMockFunction) {
              // This is probably bad practice. Consider warning here and
              // deprecating this convenience.
              initialState = null;
            }
          }
          !(typeof initialState === 'object' && !Array.isArray(initialState)) ? process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? invariant(false, '%s.getInitialState(): must return an object or null', Constructor.displayName || 'ReactCompositeComponent') : _prodInvariant('82', Constructor.displayName || 'ReactCompositeComponent') : void 0;

          this.state = initialState;
        }
```

The above component was called TransactionDetails and I have used this TransactionDetails component in transaction.jsx which looks like follows :

```
'use strict';

var Layout = require('../layout.jsx');
var React = require('react');
var Validation = require('react-validation');
var validator = require('validator');
var TextInput=require('../common/textInput.jsx');
var RadioButtonSet=require('../common/radioButtonSet.jsx');
var TransactionDetails = require('./transactionDetails.jsx');
var AddressList = require ('../suspects/AddressList.jsx');
module.exports = React.createClass({
 onClick:function(){
   console.log("I was called from transactions");
 }, 
 validateForm: function(e) {

        console.log("i am validating the form");
        var input=this.refs.transactionDetails;
        if(input.validateForm()===false){
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("There are validation errors");
        }


    },

  render: function render() {
      var populatedTransaction;
      var transactions = this.props.transactions;
      var suspects= this.props.suspects;
      var populatedSuspect = suspects[0];
      for(var i=0 ;i<transactions.length;i++){
        if(transactions[i].id===this.props.params.Id){
            populatedTransaction = transactions[i];
            break;
        }
      }
    return (
        <Layout {...this.props} addBundle='true'>
        <section className="suspects-section">
        <h2>Transactions</h2>
        <div>
        <form method="post" action="/PostTransaction" onSubmit={this.validateForm}>
        <input type="hidden" name="transaction_id" value={populatedTransaction.id} />
        <TransactionDetails ref="transactionDetails" populatedTransaction={populatedTransaction} {...this.props} />
        <input ref="numberInput" type="hidden" name="_csrf" value={this.props._csrf} />
        <input type="submit" value="Save"  />
        </form>
        </div>
        </section>
        </Layout>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try and import just `ReactBootstrap` as `var ReactBoostrap = require('react-bootstrap')` and use your row component as `<ReactBootstrap.Row>`. It works.

```
module.exports = React.createClass({

validateForm: function() {
        console.log("i am validating the transaction details");
        var input=this.refs.form;
        return(input.validateForm());

    },
render : function(){
return(
<ReactBootstrap.Row>Hello World
</ReactBootstrap.Row>
); 

}

});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0hmtkhpg/22/)**

However

```
var ReactBoostrap = require('react-bootstrap')
var Row = ReactBootstrap.Row
```

should just work fine.

Comment: You still get the same error. What about trying console.log(Row);

Comment: @medha Why are you importing as `require('react-bootstrap/lib')` If you installed react-bootstrap as `npm install -S react-bootstrap` then  `require('react-bootstrap')` works itself

Comment: Ive posted the output for Console.log(ReactBootstrap.Row)

Comment: @medha from where and how are you rendering this component. It could be a problem from there as well

Comment: Its giving an error only with bootstrap elements , with other components it works fine . Anyway I've added the component code where I'm using the component with row in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117614/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-medha).